# Javascript Handler, проверяющий, содержит ли Iframe определённые значения в элементах

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, handlers

Всем доброго времени суток. На странице есть `iframe`. Страница, которую этому `iframe`у необходимо загрузить, загружается в течение 1-3 секунд, моментально. Но вот данные в этой странице загружаются в течение 10 секунд (там всё основано на Javascript сокетах и какой-то другой белиберде..). Допустим, как только `iframe` загрузил эту страницу, некоторое поле в её исходном коде выглядит так:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="unknown" />
```

Но примерно через 10 секунд всё уже выглядит так:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="1234567890abc" />
```

Насколько я знаю, Javascript однопоточный и не имеет прав запустить какие-либо действия в новых потоках. Так вот теперь вопрос. Как создать Handler, который будет, к примеру, выдавать мне сообщение в консоль браузера о том, что в `iframe` уже нет полей со значениями `unknown`? Выглядеть всё должно примерно так:

```
...
<iframe id="page" ...></iframe>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
...
document.getElementById("page").добавитьСканер({
    while (true) {
        if (document.getElementById("page").неСодержитЗначений("unknown")) {
            Console.log("Страница загружена!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
</script>
...
```